# start up command

Tags: boot, graphics, startup, xrandr, autostart

At start up I have to open terminal and put a command in to fix the screen resolution each time. Unfortunately other people who use this computer are struggling with this.

I tried to add it to  `/etc/rc.local` by just coping the needed code to the bottom of the document, but with no joy. Maybe I need special formatting to make this work? Here is the code I need to auto execute at startup , thanks for any help. Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
cvt 1280 800 60   
xrandr --newmode "1280x800_60.00"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x800_60.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to add it to your ~/.profile  (in /home/< you username >/.profile) ?

It's better to create a startup task:
[How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: hi i made a .sh executable shell script, using #!/bin/bash .  Then added the file location  to  ubuntu preferences start up applications. worked first time.   thanks. : )